# Reformatting data in order to plot 2D continuous heatmap

Tags: r, histogram

I have data stored in a `data.frame` that I would like to plot as a continuous heat map.  I have tried using the `interp` function from `akima` package, but as the data can be very large (2 million rows) I would like to avoid this if possible as it takes a very long time.  Here is the format of my data

```
l1 <- c(1,2,3)
grid1 <- expand.grid(l1, l1)
lprobdens <- c(0,2,4,2,8,10,4,8,2)
df <- cbind(grid1, lprobdens)
colnames(df) <- c("age1", "age2", "probdens")

age1   age2  probdens
1        1       0
2        1       2
3        1       4
1        2       2
2        2       8 
3        2       10
1        3       4
2        3       8
3        3       2
```

I would like to format it in a `length(df$age1) x length(df$age2)` matrix.  I gather that once it is formatted in this manner I would be able to use basic functions such as `image` to plot a 2D histogram continuous heat map similar to that created using the `akima` package.  Here is how I think the transformed data should look.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
    1    2    3
1   0    2    4
2   2    8    8
3   4    10   2
```

It seems as though `ldply` but I can't seem to sort out how it works.

I forgot to mention, the $age information is always continuous and regular, such that the list age1 is equal to age2 but age1 >= age2.  I guess this means that it may be classed as continuous data as it stands and doesn't require the `interp` function.

Comment: How did you get to that final output? I mean, what is its desirable purpose? contingency table?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I input that format because I think this would work for plotting with `image`.  The end result should be a heat map with age1 on the x-axis and age2 on the y-axis and the probdens value plotted in heat colors.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I get it what you want. It just a matter of reshaping data with `reshape` s 'cast function. The `value.var` argument is just to avoid the warning message that R tried to guess the value to use. The result does not change if you omit it.

```
library(reshape2)
as.matrix(dcast(dat, age1 ~ age2, value.var = "probdens")[-1])
     1  2 3
[1,] 0  2 4
[2,] 2  8 8
[3,] 4 10 2
```

Comment: Very good!  thanks very much.  Can I just inquire about the purpose of the `[-1]` at the end?

Comment: Because the first column of the output of `dcast` contains the values of `age1`, of course if you want to keep them just omit the `[-1]`. I decided to omit because in fact they were 1,2,3 and so on like the normal row numeration. It could be redundant with these data, but as I said, for different ages you have to keep them.